# How to switch static files back to using HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, http

My https has just expired. I have switch my domain from https to http in wp_options table. But all my assets are still on https when I visited website, I got all assets link error with 404. How can I switch my assets back to http?

[image]

Site: http://www.kingdynasty.com.au

Answer (score 0):

Rocky.

You can try these:

1. **make sure the values changed in database**

If you can't login to 
*wp-admin > settings* to confirm that, you can go to database, wp_options table and look for siteurl and home values

2. **add code to wp-config.php**

Add these lines to *wp-config.php*

```
  define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

3. **Clear your cache**

Make sure that you clear the cache from any cache plugins you're using and also from your browser

Also try adding this to wp-config.php (note "false")

```
  define( 'WP_CACHE', false );
```

4. **check https / ssl related plugins**

You might be using any plugin which is causing this, like ssl insecure content fixer, etc.

5. **Cloudflare or other dns side redirect**

Make sure that the site isn't using any dns based redirect

6. **disable all plugins and confirm**
7. **change theme to default and check**

**Let me know any issues with this**

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to run a search and replace on your database. Run a backup first! Ideally you can do that through your host or WPCLI. If not, you could try a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

Although getting a new SSL certificate should really be your priority here!